# Not getting a return from remote coldfusion method with jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coldfusion

Update2:

Here is jQuery included (along with current jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/honors/thesis_submission/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

domain is http://uwf.edu

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#advisor_email').autocomplete({source: "/honors/thesis_submission/cfc/advisors.cfc?method=advisorLookUp&returnFormat=json", minLength: 2});
});
```

Updated method:

```
<cffunction name="advisorLookUp" access="remote" output = "false" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="term" type="string" required="no">
        <cfset var advisorLookUp = "">
        <cfset var a = []>
        <cfset var s = {}>

        <cfquery name = "advisorLookUp" datasource = "#dsn#">
        SELECT id, email
        FROM budPerson
        WHERE email like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value = "#trim(arguments.term)#%">
        </cfquery>

        <cfloop query = "advisorLookUp">
            <cfset s = StructNew()>
            <cfset s["id"] = id>
            <cfset s["label"] = email>
            <cfset s["value"] = email>
            <cfset arrayAppend(a,s)>
        </cfloop>


        <cfreturn a>
    </cffunction>
```

Form:

```
<cfform enctype="multipart/form-data" name = "coversheet">
<!-- other fields excluded -->
<input name="advisor_email" type="text" id="advisor_email" size="40"> 
<!-- other fields excluded -->
</cfform>
```

**Note again...I was able to get this working by putting the SAME code that is in my method on a regular cfm page and just cfoutputing...weird much? :\ I'd like to get it working through the remote method in my cfc.**

Update:

Switch to jQuery UI and updated my code to match it. I'm still not getting a response remotely from my method.

--

I'm trying to setup a jQuery Autocomplete plugin (specifically: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/).

I would just use the coldfusion build in autocomplete, but it was not working for me (giving me an error that apparently I can do nothing about.)

Anyway, my remote method in my cfc will not give me a response. Firebug acts like it is all good and stuff, but doesn't actually give me a return.

Here is my function:

```
<cffunction name="advisorLookUp" access="remote" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="q" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfset var advisorLookUp = "">
        <cfset var arr = "">


        <cfquery name = "advisorLookUp" datasource = "#dsn#">
        SELECT id, email
        FROM budPerson
        WHERE email like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value = "#trim(arguments.q)#%">
        </cfquery>

        <cfsavecontent variable="arr">
        <cfoutput query = "advisorLookUp">
            #advisorLookUp.email# | #advisorLookUp.id# 
        </cfoutput>
        </cfsavecontent>

        <cfreturn arr>
</cffunction>
```

I have the return being formatted the way the plugin wants. Well, that doesn't really matter I guess...I really just want to know I'm getting a response (which I'm not at the moment).

Here is my jQuery calling the method:

```
$('#advisor_email').autocomplete(
     "/honors/thesis_submission/cfc/advisors.cfc?method=advisorLookUp&returnFormat=json");
```

I've tested the method without the jQuery by just doing a invoke and it works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Im not sure, but it looks like you are missing the query string.  I am not sure if the autocomplete adds this argument for you.  Since you put required as yes, the call will fail otherwise.

Comment: just to confirm, are you using a version of coldfusion that supports json returnFormat? (I'm stuck with one that doesn't). Also, have you tried using the method manually from within a test page to ensure that the method works and returns valid json?

Comment: To debug this, take the URL that's showing in FireBug, and open it in a new tab in your browser. Debug to your heart's content until you figure out what's wrong, and then run it again in your test page.

Comment: Looks like this instance of autocomplete is depreciated and has been rolled into [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).  I'd start by replacing the depreciated plugin and using the jQuery UI plugin.  You'll likely find that it has better documentation and support since its more current.

Comment: @mbseid changing required to 'no' did not produce any results. I've already confirmed the function works on a test page by just calling it and it does return the json. I will try the jQuery UI plugin as well!

Comment: Update: switched over to using jQuery UI, no luck. Note again that my method works on a separate test page by invoking the method. Do you think it could be how i am passing the params for the ajax call? I edited my code for jQuery UI compatibility. (Changed q to 'term' and reformatted my json.)

Comment: Can you show us the whole of the relevant bits of calling page, your JQuery include, and script blocks and form. That was we could run it ourselves. Need to use firebug console to see that the call to the CFC is made, what params are actually passed,  and what is returned.

Comment: @Saul updated the stuff in my post and I also can verify that the cfc is getting a call to it according to firebug (GET: url...) just no return. Thanks everyone for help so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of ColdFusion are you running? If not the latest (version 9) then you may need to add the following if-statement to the **onRequestStart()** method in your Application.cfc to address a bug whereby the presence of the onRequest() function messes with remote calls:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="thePage" type="string" required="true">

    <!--- Other code in your onRequestStart method --->

    <!--- Add the following to the end of your onRequestStart method --->
    <cfif ListLast( arguments.thePage,"." ) IS "cfc">
        <cfset StructDelete( this, "onRequest" )>
        <cfset StructDelete( variables,"onRequest" )>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

This detects if the request a remote cfc call and removes the onRequest function.

(NB: Make sure "arguments.thePage" matches whatever name you have declared for that argument. Some people name it TargetPage or such like. Doesn't matter as long as it matches the name you declare.)

Comment: I believe I'm using 8 still, but they might have switched it on me...I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

After wrestling with this....I decided to just put the coldfusion code in my method just on some page (ajax.cfm) and do the remote call that way. It works...now. However, if anyone knows how to get this to work with a remote call to a method in a cfc I would be much happier.

```
<cfparam name="url.term" default = "">
<cfset  a = []>
<cfset s = {}>

        <cfquery name = "advisorLookUp" datasource = "#dsn#">
        SELECT id, email
        FROM budPerson
        WHERE email like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value = "#trim(url.term)#%">
        </cfquery>

        <cfloop query = "advisorLookUp">
            <cfset s = StructNew()>
            <cfset s["id"] = id>
            <cfset s["label"] = email>
            <cfset s["value"] = email>
            <cfset arrayAppend(a,s)>
        </cfloop>

        <cfoutput>#serializeJSON(a)#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tentonaxe mentions, set returnformat to json, and CF will take care of serialising and returning your struct in what looks to be correct format (at least for the JQuery version of AutoComplete)

Comment: That's a shame, it ought to work, as we use that approach a lot in our apps where I work. What you might want to try is invoking the CFC with returnformat=JSON and usign eityher FireBug network monitor or Fiddler and see what CF is actually returning. There's a problem either in the server or the client, and watching at the network level will tell you what side the problem is on. It's worth persisting with getting to the bottom of this, as once it's working, it's a very slick way of hooking up your front-end to CF.

Comment: I've used this method before on the same server...so I don't know why it isn't working this time. However, I don't personally maintain our servers so for all I know, they could have done something to make remote calls mess up and I have no clue what. :( It is almost like the server just isn't allowing them. It is just weird...cause it is only with CFC. Works fine with a CFM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you include jquery before jqueryui in your calling page. Anyway this works, on testpage set it back to the path to your cfc

testpage.cfm

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<cfform name = "coversheet">
<!-- other fields excluded -->
<input name="advisor_email" type="text" id="advisor_email" size="40"> 
<!-- other fields excluded -->
</cfform>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#advisor_email').autocomplete({source: "cfcs/advisors.cfc?method=advisorLookUp&returnFormat=json", minLength: 2});
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

advisors.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="advisorLookUp" access="remote" output = "false" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="term" type="string" required="no">
        <cfset var advisorLookUp = "">
        <cfset var a = []>
        <cfset var s = {}>
    <!--- no dsn so hardcode some data --->
        <cfset hardcodeData = queryNew("id, email")>
        <cfset queryAddRow(hardcodeData)>
        <cfset querySetCell(hardcodeData, "id", 1)>
        <cfset querySetCell(hardcodeData, "email", "petra@xyz.com")>
        <cfset queryAddRow(hardcodeData)>
        <cfset querySetCell(hardcodeData, "id", 2)>
        <cfset querySetCell(hardcodeData, "email", "pete@abc.com")>
        <cfset queryAddRow(hardcodeData)>
        <cfset querySetCell(hardcodeData, "id", 3)>
        <cfset querySetCell(hardcodeData, "email", "peter@abc.com")>

    <!--- now spoof the query --->
        <cfquery name = "advisorLookUp" dbtype="query">
                SELECT id, email
                FROM hardcodeData
                WHERE email like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value = "#trim(arguments.term)#%">
         </cfquery>


        <cfreturn advisorlookup> 
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Entering "pe" in the input box generates this in firebug responses

{"COLUMNS":["ID","EMAIL"],"DATA":[["1.0","petra@xyz.com"],["2.0","pete@abc.com"],["3.0","peter@abc.com"]]}

yes returning the query, you could fiddle if you wanted the return formatted differently

like you had it

```
   <cfloop query = "advisorLookUp">
        <cfset s = StructNew()>
        <cfset s["id"] = id>
        <cfset s["label"] = email>
        <cfset s["value"] = email>
        <cfset arrayAppend(a,s)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn a>
```

Comment: If this worked for you, then it must be something specific to my coldfusion server...or this didn't actually work. (Also, you are returning the query instead of the array of structs?) Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Your stuff should have worked, but it seems the issue was coldfusion 8 needed some extra stuff for doing the remote call.